# Is it possible to run e2fsck in a way that'll give false results?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, external-hdd, e2fsck

I have this 6 months old 5TB external hard drive. I started to experience a lot of I/O errors recently, so I backed up my data then used gparted to create a new partition table, a new main partition.

Then I ran the following code trying to see if it's a hardware problem :

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdc1`

So far I have the following results : [image: Screenshot of e2fsck results]

> Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 9.24% done, 11:44:51 elapsed. (**8333**/0/0 errors)

and I'm honestly kinda shocked, I didn't expect it to be this bad.

So I  guess my question really is :

Is it possible to get false results from e2fsck based on wrong usage of the tool ? or are these results *always* proof that the hard disk is genuinely very damaged ?

Update : Here's the smartctl results :

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-47-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD50NMZW-59BCBS0
Serial Number:    WD-WXC2DA1269FR
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2bf66ed54
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    5.000.947.523.584 bytes [5,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    4800 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Sep 11 12:26:06 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  73) The previous self-test completed having
                    a test element that failed and the test
                    element that failed is not known.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (12480) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 530) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 48799
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2875
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1290
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   185   185   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       30664
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   198   195   000    Old_age   Always       -       899
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       3812
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   194   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       20670
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1543
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       93
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      3792         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      3792         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      3792         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: Is this device mounted on the time of check?

Comment: @roaima There we go, sorry I should've thought of checking SMART data before, I'm guessing this is not great news. Thankfully I think I'm still in the guarantee period.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it's unmounted

Comment: There ! sorry , as you can see new user, thanks for your patience

Comment: Copy all the information from the disk and replace it. Check this line: `Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 48799`. ALso `Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   185   185   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       30664`

Comment: ok thanks a lot, shame about the drive. 
But at least now I don't have to wait for badblocks to finish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a broken disk. SMART values of interest (last column):

> ```
>   1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     ...   Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 48799
>   5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   ...   Pre-fail  Always       -       30664
>   9 Power_On_Hours          ...   Old_age   Always       -       3812
> 194 Temperature_Celsius     ...   Old_age   Always       -       52
> 196 Reallocated_Event_Count ...   Old_age   Always       -       1543
> 197 Current_Pending_Sector  ...   Old_age   Always       -       93
> 198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ...   Old_age   Offline      -       0
> ```

The only other comment about this obviously failed disk is that the temperature seems a little higher that might be normal. Is there enough airflow around the disk?

Since it's only six months old I would try to get it replaced with a new one by the seller as "faulty when purchased". However, failing that you will get a warranty replacement from Western Digital - see https://support-en.wd.com/app/warrantystatusweb and enter your serial number starting `WX`.

There is little point doing anything more with it except,

- Trying to rescue any data still on the disk for which you don't have a backup (use `ddrescue` at this point - nothing else will touch it)
- Registering that warranty claim

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I bought it from a retailer (Europe) and I think they normally handle it for you if your guarantee is still intact, I wonder if they'll just direct me to the warranty claim by WD though.